# how to change Validator isStrongPassword requirements

Tags: reactjs, validation, passwords

I want to change the requirements of [Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) isStrongPassword instead of these Default options:

```
{ minLength: 8, minLowercase: 1, minUppercase: 1, 
minNumbers: 1, minSymbols: 1, returnScore: false, 
pointsPerUnique: 1, pointsPerRepeat: 0.5, 
pointsForContainingLower: 10, pointsForContainingUpper: 10, 
pointsForContainingNumber: 10, pointsForContainingSymbol: 10 }
```

I need to make it without `minSymbols:` is there a way to change these conditions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `isStrongPassword(str [, options])` and for minSymbols just set value 0. Options are this object that you posted.

Comment: i didn't get it

Comment: Search here -> https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js isStrongPassword and change options as I said above.